# compiling qt project give undefined reference to operator delete(void*, unsigned int)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross compile and create a deb file from a qt project with the command dpkg-buildpackage. I am using the yocto qt sdk :"poky-atmel-glibc-x86_64-atmel-qt5-demo-image-cortexa5hf-vfp-toolchain-2.1.1.sh"
I have installed it and runned the environment-setup-cortexa5hf-vfp-poky-linux-gnueabi file.
I haved updated the qtchooser to be as :

```
/opt/poky-atmel/2.1.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/qt5
/opt/poky-atmel/2.1.1/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib
```

I have set the qmake file in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-

Im getting the folowing error:

```
/usr/lib/../lib/libQt5Widgets.so: undefined reference to operator delete(void*, unsigned int)@CXXABI_1.3.9'
/usr/lib/../lib/libQt5Widgets.so: undefined reference to operator delete[](void*, unsigned int)@CXXABI_1.3.9'
/usr/lib/../lib/libQt5Core.so: undefined reference to __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8'
```

using ubuntu 14.04 64 cross-compiling for armhf

any help would be appreciated

edit:
I think the problem is because I am using 64 bit system or g++ old version (4.8.4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the problem. the problem was using libraries compiled with newer g++ 5.3 with older g++ 4.7. so I downloaded the poky 1.6 qt sdk, and installed it, then I managed to create deb file